# How to create folders in Vim (by preference using NERDTree)?

Tags: vim, directory

I know how to create rename, delete and move files in **NERDTree** (just pressing `m then either [a, d, or m]`). But I can't figure out how to create a folder.

Does anybody know how to do this on **NERDTree** (or just in vim's native "way")?

Comment: Thanks for asking as I didn't actually know you could move files in NERDTree (but had an inkling you could) and searching led me here. Perhaps I'm blind, but couldn't find any mention of moving files in the help screen.

Comment: if i have the cursor on a file in NERDTree and then press d gvim says "E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off". Do I need to add something into vimrc ? ....got it and slightly edited question

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You use `m + a` and put a trailing `/` on the name of the child node you want to create.

E.g., `m + a + foo` creates the file `foo`.  `m + a + foo/` creates the directory `foo`.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you can always do:

```
:!mkdir <directory>
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

When in the NERDTree window, press 'm'; you should see a menu at the bottom. Type in 'a' for add childnode. Now input the directory you want to create, making sure to add a '/' at the end, otherwise the script would create a file.