# NERDTree - how to delete file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

How to delete a file with [NERDTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658)?

I have put this into my `.vimrc` file:

```
set modifiable
```

but I don't know the command to delete!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This
[How to create folders in Vim (by preference using NERDTree)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102115/how-to-create-folders-in-vim-by-preference-using-nerdtree)
should give an answer. Just type `m` in NERDTree window and a dialogue appears in a QuickFix window

In addition there has been made a plugin on top of nerdtree https://github.com/ivalkeen/nerdtree-execute which allows to execute files with `m`+`x` -> I use it to open pdfs I get from compiling LaTeX

Comment: I Updated my answer to make aware of a recent plugin.

Comment: I cannot see anything except beauty, thanks a lot for nominating this awesome plugin.