# How can I delete the current file in vim?

Tags: vim

How can I delete from the disk the current open file from within vim? Would be nice to also close the buffer.

I see you [can use NERDTree for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615294/nerdtree-how-to-delete-file), but I don't use this plugin.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Using an external tool such as *rm*(1) is fine, but Vim also has its own [`delete()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#delete%28%29) function for deleting files. This has the advantage of being portable.

```
:call delete(expand('%'))
```

An alternative way of expressing this is `:call delete(@%)`, which uses the [`%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote%25) (current file) register (tip by @accolade).

To completely purge the current buffer, both the file representation on disk and the Vim buffer, append [`:bdelete`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:bdelete):

```
:call delete(expand('%')) | bdelete!
```

You'll probably want to map this according to your preferences.

Comment: Thanks! The following map in the .vimrc seems to work: `nnoremap rm :call delete(expand('%')) \| bdelete!<CR>`. You might want to add in your answer.

Comment: That mapping isn't ideal. We don't want to break the [`r`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#r) command! Better prefix your mapping with [`<Leader>...`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapleader).

Comment: isn't ideal even because it is easy to delete the file and close the buffer without intention!! But I needed this only as a temporary solution.

Comment: I mapped it to Ctrl+Del using `nnoremap <C-Del> :call delete(expand('%'))<CR>` but I don't close the buffer in case it happens by accident; then you still have a chance to save it.

Comment: Note: `expand(s)` is a special-purpose function that can be used to get the current file relative path with `s = '%'`, relative current directory with `s = '%:h'`, and the absolute versions with `s = '%:p'` and `s = '%:p:h`, among a small bunch of other less interesting things.

Comment: `:call delete(@%)|q!` ← Short variant (if you don't want to map it).  (The buffer remains in `:ls` and can be revived with `:b` this way; it retains the filename and buffer options, but not the file content.)

Comment: @accolade,  I like your trick, but you would need to use `:call delete(@%)|bd!` and use `:ls!` with `:b` to revive.

Comment: @Bart Thanks! :)  What I wrote holds true, I just tested it again.  So `:q!` instead of `:bd!` (1 keystroke saved! \o/ ) works fine.  Maybe I don't understand your comment right?  Anyways, interesting pointer to `:ls!` (and its difference to `:ls`).

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev, `%`, `%:h` etc. are relative only if that's how you opened the file: relatively.  If you open a text file e.g. from Windows Explorer, `%` is already absolute (so `== %:p`).

Comment: **DATA HAZARD WARNING!** With just `%` (filepath ("*filename*" in vim terminology) as originally invoked, potentially relative, e.g. just the file's name) instead of `%:p` (absolute filepath) you run a small of risk of deleting a file of the same name in another directory instead, if you have forgotten you `:cd`ed there.  Therefore I strongly recommend using `expand('%:p')` instead of `@%` or `expand('%')` if you map it anyway.

Answer (score 109):

Take a look at [Delete files with a Vim command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Delete_files_with_a_Vim_command). The [Comments](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Delete_files_with_a_Vim_command#Comments) section should have what you're looking for:

> Basically, Rm will delete the current file; RM will delete the current file and quit the buffer (without saving) in one go.

Alternatively, you could just issue a shell command to remove the current file:

```
:!rm %
```

Comment: It is something so simple that I almost can't believe I need to create a script for this. Thanks.

Comment: deleting with `!rm %`, is there a way to avoid the warning when vim get back to the buffer?

Comment: With some special characters in file name, this command would not work, like if the file name is 20130711-contacts #285.vcf, which has space, it would say 'rm: cannot remove `20130711-contacts': No such file or directory'

Comment: @saeed144, in the case of spaces in a filename (or other characters you don't want interpreted at the shell level), you'll want to surround the filename (`%`) with quotes: `!rm "%"`.

Comment: **DATA HAZARD WARNING!** With just `%` (filepath ("*filename*" in vim terminology) as originally invoked, potentially relative, e.g. just the file's name) instead of `%:p` (absolute filepath) you run a small of risk of deleting a file of the same name in another directory instead, if you have forgotten you `:cd`ed there.  Therefore I strongly recommend using `%:p` instead of `%` if you map it anyway.

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes a plugin can be an attractive solution even for a simple problem. In this case we're lucky as there is [***eunuch.vim***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4300) by the almighty Tim Pope.

In its own words *eunuch.vim* provides

> Vim sugar for the UNIX shell commands that need it the most. Delete or rename a buffer and the underlying file at the same time. Load a `find` or a `locate` into the quickfix list. And so on.

Perfect. It has what we need, plus some additional tools if we're on a UNIX system.

The command you are looking for is

```
:Remove!
```

Again, remap it if you need it a lot, e.g. `:nnoremap <Leader>rm :Remove!<CR>`.

Comment: I was looking a way to do without plugins, so I'll accept your other answer. The plugin looks good :-)

Comment: This plugin is pretty convenient if you need vim ways of `mv`, `mkdir`, `find`, etc. HIghly recommend.

Answer (score 6):

I like being able to delete files from within vim, but I am also paranoid about accidentally deleting important work that, for one reason or another, is not yet under version control. I find it useful to combine the previous information from @glts and @accolade with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672367/2166823) on how to use the `confirm` command to prompt before quitting vim.

Putting these together, I added a function to my `~/.vimrc`, which prompts before deleting the file and closing the buffer, and mapped it to a key combination:

```
nnoremap <Leader>d. :call DeleteFileAndCloseBuffer()

fun! DeleteFileAndCloseBuffer()
  let choice = confirm("Delete file and close buffer?", "&Do it!\n&Nonono", 1)
  if choice == 1 | call delete(expand('%:p')) | q! | endif
endfun
```

If you are one keystroke less paranoid than I am, you can append `<CR>` to the first line

```
nnoremap <Leader>d. :call DeleteFileAndCloseBuffer()<CR>
```

and only have to press return once.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `expand('%:p')` instead of `@%` when you script it anyway.  (While I'm flattered that you incorporated my hint :) the brevity benefit is marginal in a script.  More importantly: )  `%:p` will expand the filename to a full absolute path (which it may or may not already be).  With just `%` you run a small of risk of deleting a file of the same name in another directory instead, if you have forgotten you `:cd`ed there.

Comment: Thanks for pionting that out! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I guess you could make a copy of the file to some dir before deleting,  and then cleaning files from that once every x week?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two steps:

1. save as a new file

   :w newfilename
2. delete the old file

   ! rm oldfilename

Answer (score 0):

This may be an unpopular opinion but your file tree explorer (Netrw/NerdTree) is going to be the simplest and safest way to delete a file. Even if OP is not using NerdTree, the in-built plugin Netrw will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

In lua with confirmation prompt:

```lua
local function confirm_and_delete_buffer()
  local confirm = vim.fn.confirm("Delete buffer and file?", "&Yes\n&No", 2)

  if confirm == 1 then
    os.remove(vim.fn.expand "%")
    vim.api.nvim_buf_delete(0, { force = true })
  end
end
```

I mapped to `<leader>df` but yall do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**"^R%" to see the filename**

Here is a "full" example with a normal mode (noremap) mapping onto `,D`

```
nn ,D :echo delete("^R%") <Bar> bd
```

This gives you a command with the expanded filename inserted, so you can confirm by entering. The `echo` shows 0 (success) or -1. `bd` without the `!` fails when buffer is modified, which for me makes sense.

For more verbosity and clearer programming, a function can be defined:

```
fu Delete (cur)
   let cur = a:cur
   if delete(cur)
        echo "OOPS:" . cur  
   else 
        echo "GONE:" . cur  
        bd
   endif  
endfu
```

This time it is just a call (to map as above):

```
:call Delete("^R%")
```